# DataTables in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I have a string, named s respectively. The **string s** looks like :

```
    "HD-M-16-H-000001*1001*1       HD-M-16-H-000001*1001         HD-M-16-H 000001  15 JUL 201614 JUL 20170816ACHEONG SIEW FUNG                                                                    12345678I   22 DEC 1960SPO      F-                                                                                                 
     HD-M-16-H-000001*1001*2       HD-M-16-H-000001*1001         HD-M-16-H 000001  15 JUL 201614 JUL 20170816ACHEONG SIEW FUNG                                                                    12345678I   22 DEC 1960SPO      F-                                                                                                 
     HD-M-16-H-000001*1001*3       HD-M-16-H-000001*1001         HD-M-16-H 000001  15 JUL 201614 JUL 20170816ACHEONG SIEW FUNG                                                                    12345678I   22 DEC 1960SPO      F-  "
```

I split the string based on rows. The code is

```
   string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
   string[] Mem = s.Split('\r');
```

So, Now the string[] **Mem** looks like :

```
 "HD-M-16-H-000001*1001*1       HD-M-16-H-000001*1001         HD-M-16-H 000001  15 JUL 201614 JUL 20170816ACHEONG SIEW FUNG                                                                    12345678I   22 DEC 1960SPO      F- "                                                                                                
 "HD-M-16-H-000001*1001*2       HD-M-16-H-000001*1001         HD-M-16-H 000001  15 JUL 201614 JUL 20170816ACHEONG SIEW FUNG                                                                    12345678I   22 DEC 1960SPO      F-  "                                                                                               
 "HD-M-16-H-000001*1001*3       HD-M-16-H-000001*1001         HD-M-16-H 000001  15 JUL 201614 JUL 20170816ACHEONG SIEW FUNG                                                                    12345678I   22 DEC 1960SPO      F-  "
```

Now, actually i am looking to create a dataTable with 'n' number of columns to hold Each word of each string in **Mem**.

The below code that takes each line of string[] and holds it into string. Then i split the string

```
 string firststr = Mem.First();
 string secondstr = Mem[1];
 string thirdstr = Mem[2];

 string str = firststr.Substring(0, 30);
 string[] m = str.Split('\r');
```

Actually i want to store all the three string[] to  one string datatype with 3 strings and split each line of string by substr using loop(foreach or While). So how can i acheive this???

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: if you want all three string[] in one string then why did you split it into an array, it already is in one string. So just do a substring on it.

Comment: Yeah. Before i split its only one string. But i want it as 3 strings

Comment: So substring it like you said. Or reword your question so people know what you are asking because I am not clear on what you are asking.

Comment: you just need an array of arrays.  Assuming you have the same number of columns in each row you can just iterate over your "m" collection and split each "string" into an additional array which is stored in a multidimensional array for your data.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx  .   Also datatables can handle an array of arrays as a data source.